# php to javascript loop

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

**Question**

I'm trying to place markers on a map by retrieving them via php, looping them into javascript arrays then looping the arrys to add the markers.

db query

```
require_once("func/connect.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM site_locations;";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

creating creating js arrays

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lat = new Array();
    var lon = new Array();
    var site = new Array();

    <?php 
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $lat = json_encode($row['latitude']);
        $long = json_encode($row['longitude']);
        $site = json_encode($row['site_name']);

        ?>
        lat.push(<?php  echo '\'';
                        echo $lat;
                        echo '\''; ?>);


        lon.push(<?php  echo '\'';
                        echo $lon;
                        echo '\''; ?>);

        site.push(<?php  echo '\'';
                        echo $site;
                        echo '\''; ?>);

        <?php
    }
    ?>
</script>
```

Finally adding looping the js arrays to add markers

```
    markers: [
        for (i = 0; i < lat.length; i++) {
            {
                latLng: [lat[i], lon[i]],
                name: site[i]
            },
        }
    ]
```

As it currently stands, this does not work. The PHP side of things works.

Also tried

```
    markers: [
        for (var i = 0; i < lat.length; i++) {
            {
                latLng: [lat(i), lon(i)],
                name: site(i)
            },
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Looks like an issue with the illegal string literal termination

Comment: not sure about the PHP syntax `lat.push(<?php  echo '\'$lat\''; ?>);`

Comment: You cannot have a for loop statement inside a literal array statement

Comment: @PatrickEvans the for loops is outside of the while loop, is that what you mean?

Comment: No I mean, `markers: [  for (var .... ` you would get an error trying to do this.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Ah, okay. Thank you I'll consider that in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the work on the PHP side :

```
<?php 
    $points = array();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $point = new stdClass();
        $coords = array();
        $coords[] = floatval($row['latitude']);
        $coords[] = floatval($row['longitude']);
        $point->latLng = $coords;
        $point->name = $row['site_name'];

        array_push($points, $point);
    }
?>

<script>
var points = <?php echo json_encode($points); ?>;
</script>
```

And then init your maps with the javascript variable :

```
markers: points
```

Comment: I'm having a play around to try and get it to work, seems like a few errors kick up. I'll sort it and check to see if we have any luck

Comment: Just changed the var points to an echo, $points to an array push and it works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You already `json_encode()` the values, hence the single quotes in js are breaking it. Use:

```
site.push(<?php  echo $site; ?>);
```

Comment: ah yes, this is true thank you for pointing that out. However, It apparently isn't the only school-boy-error in my code.